# python beautifulsoup adds html tags to svg

Tags: python, svg, beautifulsoup

While parsing an **SVG** file, I noticed that beautifulsoup adds **html** tags to it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<svg></svg>', 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

results in:

```
<html><body><svg></svg></body></html>
```

Why is this so and can this be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use [`lxml`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) parser, which is HTML parser. To parse XML you should use [`xml`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<svg></svg>', 'xml')
print(soup)                       # ^^^^^^
```

From BeautifulSoup documentation:

> Beautiful Soup presents the same interface to a number of different
>   parsers, but each parser is different. Different parsers will create
>   different parse trees from the same document. *The biggest differences
>   are between the HTML parsers and the XML parsers.* Here’s a short
>   document, parsed as HTML:
>
> ```
> BeautifulSoup("<a><b /></a>")
> # <html><head></head><body><a><b></b></a></body></html>
> ```
>
> Since an empty  tag is not valid HTML, the parser turns it into a
>    tag pair.
>
> Here’s the same document parsed as XML (running this requires that you
>   have lxml installed). Note that the empty  tag is left alone, and
>   that the document is given an XML declaration instead of being put
>   into an  tag.:
>
> ```
> BeautifulSoup("<a><b /></a>", "xml")
> # <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> # <a><b/></a>
> ```

Source: [Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers), emphasis mine.